# if template alias declaration resolve to a new family of types?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

considering following code :

what happens when we use a template alias, as in X? Is the specialization X still used, since Z is an alias for Y?
what happens when we use a template alias , if template alias declaration resolve to a new family of types ?

```
#include <iostream>

template <template <typename> class>
struct X {
  X() { std::cout << "1"; }
};

template <typename>
struct Y {};

template <typename T>
using Z = Y<T>;

template <>
struct X<Y> {
  X() { std::cout << "2"; }
};

int main() {
  X<Y> x1;
  X<Z> x2;
}

output :21
```

Comment: I would expect `22` to be printed, as `Z` is merely an alias for `Y`. g++ prints `22`, but clang prints `21`...

Comment: yes , why you get different out put

Comment: I think that the wording was not clear before, but should be fixed now to make *true* alias really identical (same template argument with same order).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alias is merely an alias, and does not introduce a new family of types. In fact, running your code prints `22` - this is because `Z`is an alias for `Y`, therefore the specialization is getting hit twice.

Unfortunately, while g++ prints `22` as expected, clang prints `21`. I suspect it's due to [bug #26093](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=26093). In fact, converting the `template` templates to normal templates prevents the bug from occurring:

```
template <typename>
struct X {
    X() { std::cout << "1"; }
};

struct Y {};
using Z = Y;

template <>
struct X<Y> {
    X() { std::cout << "2"; }
};

int main() {
    X<Y> x1;
    X<Z> x2;
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HautXwK6fhWK1Jsz)

Comment: but According to §14.5.7 paragraph 1 in the standard, a template alias declaration resolve to a new family of types. The specialization cannot be used, and the first template declaration is used instead, printing 1. im confused its bug or new standard in c++14

Comment: The standard says [it's *"a family of types"*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.alias), not *"a **new** family of types"*.

Comment: wandbox gives me 21     http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/n5vIKLCGFXO6Qvm7

Comment: @Adib: yes, as expected due to bug #26093. If you try my modified code *(the one in my answer)*, it gives `22` for both gcc and clang.